# How to fix regular expression for my need?

Tags: javascript, regex

## Question

### Given String

```
let string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)";
```

### Required output

```
[foo , (bar) , baz , (blim) , (hhh(kkk)thfgg)];
```

## Tried 1#

```js
let string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)"

console.log(string.split(/(\(.*\))/m))
```

### My output

```
[
  "foo",
  "(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)",
  ""
]
```

## Tried 2

```js
let string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)"

console.log(string.split(/(\([a-z]{0,}\))/g))
```

### My output

```
[
  "foo",
  "(bar)",
  "baz",
  "(blim)",
  "(hhh",
  "(kkk)",
  "thfgg)"
]
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong , why , & How to solve the problem.

I am new to regex so explanation of  the basics well of your answer is going to be great for me .

Comment: how  to achieve the question out put

Comment: You are looking for a recursive pattern which is not supported in `JavaScript`. So you need to count opening and closing brackets in a function yourself.

Comment: can you explain how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator function in `JavaScript` (I'm not a `JS` programmer, so the code might look a bit clumsy):

```js
    function* parser(some_string) {
        let stack = "", pars = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < some_string.length; i++) {
            if (some_string[i] == "(") {
                if ((pars == 0) && (stack.length > 0)) {
                    yield stack;
                    stack = "";
                }
                stack += some_string[i];
                pars += 1;
            } else if (some_string[i] == ")") {
                stack += some_string[i];
                pars -= 1;
                if ((pars == 0) && (stack.length > 0)) {
                    yield stack;
                    stack = "";
                }
            } else if (i == some_string.length - 1) {
                if (stack.length > 0) {
                    yield stack;
                    stack = "";
                }
            } else {
                stack += some_string[i];
            }
    
        }
    }
    
    let string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)";
    
    const it = parser(string);
    
    for(item of it) {
        console.log(item);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, "I'm not a JS programmer", but I'll just whip up a quick parser using a generator function and use `for of` on its output

Comment: @JuanMendes: Well, of course, I know the general concept from other programming languages and parsing in general. But thanks :-)

Comment: Yaa it's working pretty well , I took some time to learn the logic of the function , Than you for your ans . Would u mind to upvote the question !!

Answer (score 1):

The old fashioned way works pretty well

```js
let string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(k(k)k)thfgg)aaaa";

function* parse(input) {
    let str = '';
    for (
      let i = 0, parens = 0, c = input[0], length = input.length;
      i < length;
      c = input[++i]
    ) {
      if (c === '(') {
        if (parens++) str += '(' 
        else { if (str) yield str; str = '('; }
      } else if (c === ')') {
        if (parens-- === 1) { yield str + ')'; str= '' }
        else str += ')'
      } else str += c
    }
    yield str;
}

console.log(Array.from(parse(string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take your output from this:

```
[
  "foo",
  "(bar)",
  "baz",
  "(blim)",
  "(hhh",
  "(kkk)",
  "thfgg)"
]
```

and then for each item, while the count of `(` is not the same as the count of `)`, append the next item in the list to it:

```js
const string = "foo(bar)baz(blim)(hhh(kkk)thfgg)"
const output = string.split(/(\([a-z]{0,}\))/g)

for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    while ((output[i].match(/\(/g) || []).length !== (output[i].match(/\)/g) || []).length) {
        output[i] += output.splice(i+1, 1);
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Yaa seems  usefull , but I will wait for sometime to see others incoming answers